# Basic example of how to use ImmutableJS Records with Flow

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

In the following example, I'd expect every `.get()` and `.set()` call to have a flow error, but only a couple do:

```
const ABRecord = Record({ a: 1, b: 2 });
const myRecord = ABRecord({ b: 3 });

const c = myRecord.get("c");            // ERROR
const d: string = myRecord.get("a");    // NO ERROR
myRecord.set("c", 4);                   // ERROR
myRecord.set("a", "a string");          // NO ERROR
```

Am I missing some annotations that would solve this?